# incompatible pointer to integer although using char of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

I'm new to the world of C programming, and I as trying to code a primitive, terminal-based version of the "Hangman" game.

One of the steps doing this (or at least the way I am working on), is to create a second char array (next to the original char array that stores the word one needs to guess), filled with "*" for every Char of the original array, and display it. Although the rest of the programming part is not there yet (since I am not finished with it yet), I doubt it is relevant for now (however I allready know how to proceed, that is if I weren't bothered by some error-messages)....

Here's the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void hiddenArray(char array[]);

char *secretWord;
char *arrayCover;
char letter;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

secretWord = "Test";

printf("Welcome to the Hangman!\n\n");

hiddenArray(secretWord);
printf("What is the hidden Word?: %c\n", *arrayCover);  

printf("Guess a letter\n");
scanf("%c", &letter); 


}

void hiddenArray(char array[]){

int size,i;
size = sizeof(*array);

for (i=0;i<size-1;i++){
    *(arrayCover+i) = "*";
}
}
```

Now I have two issues... the first one: 
I don't understand the error message I am getting after compilation:

```
pendu.c:41:19: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [2]' [-Wint-conversion]
            *(arrayCover+i) = "*";
                            ^ ~~~
1 warning generated.
```

And my second question: the second Array created, filled with "*" is not being displayed, what did I do wrong?

I'd love for some help, cheers!

Comment: This program has too many errors (segmentation) :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program have some errors to be corrected .

1) Your `*arraycover` is pointing to some unknown value, You have not initialized it.

2) `sizeof(*array)` should be `sizeof(array)`

3) `*(arrayCover+i) = "*"` should be `*(arrayCover+i) = '*'`;

I suggest you not to create too many global variables when you dont really need them

Create `char secretWord[100] = "Test"` instead of  `char *secretWord`

Comment: actually sizeof(array) throws a warning    sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'char *' instead of 'char []'   , while using sizeof(*array) works

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
size = sizeof(arrayCover)/sizeof(char);

for (i=0;i<size-1;i++){
    *(array+i) = '*';
}
```

Despite of all these, I think you need to allocate memory for `arrayCover`

```
arrayCover = malloc(sizeof(char) * number_of_elements);
```

Comment: Yes! thank you, I don't get why I forgot to allocate the memory... Also indeed, the '*' was obvious, again, rookie mistake. Thank You!

Comment: ... now on a different topic, but the array filled with '*' doesn't display properly, for every '*' the output is a '?'; is that just a format issue / token missing in front of the '*'?

Comment: Hmmm. To be honest, your program has many problems. First tell me what these two lines `printf("What is the hidden Word?: %c\n", *arrayCover);  

printf("Guess a letter\n");
scanf("%c", &letter); ` are doing in your program?

Comment: the first one displays the word with each char replaced by a '*'- while every time a letter will be guessed , the corresponding '*' at the position of the guessed letter (if it were to be in the word) would be replaced by the terminal-input letter (therefore the printf(guess a letter) and the scanf to bind the current input to a variable for once I code the loops comparing the letter to each element of the word, and replacing the '*' in the hidden array position in which it occurs in the orginial array by the letter)

Comment: OK. Could you you give me an example of an input and the expected output?

Comment: An exmaple would be after the "guess a letter" print , you just input whatever letter you'd like, let's go with "t"; then the program would print the hidden word as T**t, tell you how many tries you have left, and ask for the next letter until the guess-counter arrived at 0, or the entire word has been guessed right

Answer (score 0):

`"*"` is a string. Use `'*'` instead to get the char.

Comment: And what about `size = sizeof(*array); for (i=0;i<size-1;i++){//..}` ?

Answer (score 0):

`"*"` is a string which also contains `\0` also, resulting to 2 characters. Instead use `'*'` which is just a character.

The function `hiddenArray` has the formal argument `array` which need to be used locally instead of `arrayCover` as below,

```
void hiddenArray(char array[]){
   int size,i;
   size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
   for (i=0;i<size-1;i++){
         *(array+i) = '*'; /* Or array[i] = '*' */
   }
}
```